# Different encoding in junit

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

when I am running test from IntelliJ side

```
System.getProperty("file.encoding")
```

return UTF-8 (this is what I expect)

But when I am building like mvn clean install

```
System.getProperty("file.encoding")
```

return CP1250

How can I set UTF-8 in MVN?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure in your pom:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

cause I assume you have warnings in your build

Comment: I don't have any warnings in build, but I am getting wrong test result because I have some specific utf-8 characters which in cp1250 are not working proper

Comment: can you post your log output ? Hm..furthermore where do you have the utf-8 character? In property files? Which JDK version do you use? Which encoding has your whole project?